# Radare2 ptrace can not attach

Tags: binary-analysis, linux, radare2, binary

**First my setup:** 
Linux Mint 64bit 4.15.0-20-generic

radare2 the newest version from github

/etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf = 0

**Executable:**
ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64

read write and executable, i can run it with gdb or execute it from terminal

*Name = crackme01*

**What ive done as root:**

i verified with
 `ps -ef | grep gdb 
 ps -ef | grep ptrace
  ps -ef | grep r2` that only my single r2 is trying to attach.
then:

`1. r2 -d crackme01 
  2. doo`

**The error i am getting:**

> ptrace (PT_ATTACH): Operation not permitted

I found other questions from people with the same problem, but none of their solutions could solve my problem. I would really appreciate it, if someone could help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message probably should be ignored. I found something on the radare2 [github](https://github.com/radare/radare2/issues/13404)

> "These ptrace (PT_ATTACH): Operation not permitted messages seem to
>   happen because of subsequent PT_ATTACH calls to the same pid, even
>   though it is already attached. This should be fixed, but it probably
>   shouldn't cause any major issues right now." ~thestr4ng3r

In my case i also did some mistake with radare2 (i forgot to analyse `aaa`), thats the reason it "didnt work". I ignored this message, proceeded and solved this beginner crackme.

Comment: Great to see that you have solved your problem. You can now mark this answer as accepted, so that others can see the problem has been solved.

Comment: i must wait until tomorrow to do that, but i will.

Comment: still 1 hour until i can set this as the accepted answer, 2 days ago it said i need to wait 1 day